# How to build the Poco C++ libraries

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I'm trying to build the Poco C++ libraries manually on Android, iOS, and windows.  After much effort I got them to build on Android, but I'm struggling a bit on Windows.

I've had to manually edit several files already to resolve undefined symbols -- specifically File & Path weren't #included properly by *_WIN32U.cpp versions.

I'm down to what APPEARS to be my last compiler issue for "Foundation".  It's this line in Process_WIN32U.cpp:

```
    envChars = getEnvironmentVariablesBuffer(env);
```

The compiler error generated is:
        "getEnvironmentVariablesBuffer identifier not found"

The declaration of "getEnvironmentVariablesBuffer" is in Process.cpp but it's not a member of the root class, there are no EXTERN references anywhere, and no header file contains the function declaration.

So how the heck is "Process_WIN32U.cpp" supposed to be able to see that function?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but maybe you could use openFrameworks: http://openframeworks.cc/about/

Comment: Which version: Basic, Complete or Extended?  Which compiler are you using?  How are you building it?  Are you using one of the cmd files supplied?  Are you building the Windows version or the Android version?

Comment: I'm creating my own Visual Studio 2013 projects for Foundation, Crypto, Data, etc.  These are building static libraries.  As mentioned, I'm building Android, iOS, and Windows -- all with my own hand-built project files.The Android version seems to build fine, but I'm having this one particular issue on Windows.  What I've done for the moment is just include "Process.cpp" in my "Foundation" project -- not the "Process_WIN32U.cpp" file.  This seems like it won't work properly, but the Win32U file has no access to the "getEnvironmentVariablesBuffer" function because it's static to "Process.cpp".

Comment: Poco builds smoothly out-of-the-box on Windows, Linux and OSX as well as for iOS and Android. On windows, VS solutions for versions 2008-2013 are provided. Additionally, there is CMake support as well as two build scripts - [batch file](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/buildwin.cmd) and [PowerShell](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/buildwin.ps1). You must be doing something strange and it would help if you post some more information, e.g. what version of poco, how are you building it and what are exactly the errors.

Comment: The version I'm building is from last Friday, downloaded directly from the website.  I'm not using the out-of-the-box build scripts because they don't product what I need.  As already stated, I'm manually creating VS 2013 project files for each chunk of Poco and building static libraries.  The only issue I have so far with the "Foundation" project is above in my original post.  From what I can see, it's impossible for that file to access that "external" function because it's wrapped in an unnamed namespace in the other file.  So which of the two files should be in my project?

Comment: NOTE: I don't think this is a question for people who just use the automated build scripts.  It's a deeper level question as to how the plain vs. Win32U files are structured.  From what I can see looking at the source, there's no way the Win32U version could ever compile.

Comment: There certainly is a way because I build it almost daily, see e.g. [File.cpp](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/src/File.cpp#L22-L36)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how the heck is "Process_WIN32U.cpp" supposed to be able to see that function?

ProcessWIN32U.cpp (i.e. ProcessImpl class) is able to see that function because ProcessWIN32U.cpp is [included from Process.cpp](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/9d259ac02f880a486ebef30acc4e5e83d3e87b5f/Foundation/src/Process.cpp#L64) and it was not designed or meant to be used standalone - it is [excluded from build](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/Foundation_x64_vs120.vcxproj#L905-L912) in POCO Visual Studio solutions.

Answer (score -1):

In order to get ProcessWIN32U.cpp to be included by Process.cpp, one must manually /D_WIN32 which is not defined by Visual Studio (it defines WIN32).

Comment: Incorrect, see [Predefined Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx): ```_WIN32 Defined for applications for Win32 and Win64. Always defined.```

Comment: It's 100% true and 100% reproducable on two PCs in our office.

Comment: The _WIN32 macro is a global name reserved for implementers by C++ standard (see 17.4.3.2.1). As such, it is defined by MS compilers and  defining it yourself means looking for trouble. But we are really going off on a tangent. I hope I have answered your original question and would appreciate if you would accept it. We can discuss _WIN32 in another thread.

Comment: I've clicked the checkmark.  If there's something else I need to do let me know. And thanks!